# Printing Values in Dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I cannot get values inside my python dictionairy, created from a json file, to print at all. Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "Questions": [
    {
      "Q1":"What is capital of egypt?",
      "T":"London",
      "2":"France",
      "3":"Egypt"
    },

    {
      "Q2":"What is capital of USA?",
      "T":"London",
      "2":"France",
      "3":"Egypt"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my python:

```
import json
with open("questions.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["Questions"]["Q1"])
```

This returns the error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

What am I doing wrong? I have checked the syntax for printing and it all seems correct.

Comment: Will `data["Questions"][0]["Q1"]` work? As long as you have list there.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: `loads` is for loading strings. The OP clearly said they have a file (though, whether it's a file or a string for the purposes of this question is irrelevant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good strategy is to start by removing code until it works. For example, instead of

```
print(data["Questions"]["Q1"])`
```

You should try

```
print(data["Questions"])`
```

The output from this is

```
[{'Q1': 'What is capital of egypt?', 'T': 'London', '2': 'France', '3': 'Egypt'}, 
{'Q2': 'What is capital of USA?', 'T': 'London', '2': 'France', '3': 'Egypt'}]
```

From there, you can try to index like you were doing in the question:

```
[{'Q1': 'What is capital of egypt?', 'T': 'London', '2': 'France', '3': 'Egypt'}, 
{'Q2': 'What is capital of USA?', 'T': 'London', '2': 'France', '3': 'Egypt'}]['Q1']
```

Except that doesn't make sense, because you're trying to index a list, and indexes in a list are ints, not strings.

So to get the result you're expecting, you should use `data["Questions"][0]` to index the first question.

A better solution, in my opinion, is to change the structure of the JSON to something that makes a little more sense. This is how I would do it:

```
{
    "Questions": {
        "Q1": {
            "Q":"What is capital of egypt?",
            "T":"London",
            "2":"France",
            "3":"Egypt"
        },

        "Q2" : {
            "Q":"What is capital of USA?",
            "T":"London",
            "2":"France",
            "3":"Egypt"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can perform a lookup with `Q1` or `Q2` just like you expect.

Comment: I see your edit now, yes, this is much easier to come back to. Thanks- I have changed the json. Works as expected. But, one other thing I'd like to do is create a function that displays the first two answers (T & 2) using a for loop. Is this possible, or just easier to have 2 separate prints and type it for each questions.

Comment: @S.Stevens That is another way to solve the problem. I thought that changing the JSON to a format that seems to make more sense to you would be a better solution, but you do what you think best!

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion- I prefer it.

Comment: @S.Stevens I don't know if you're still working on this, but if you want to loop through a dictionary you can do that with `for question in data["Questions"].values():` which will put the dictionary pointed to by "Q1" or "Q2" in the variable `question`, you can then get T & 2 by indexing with `question["T"]` or `question["2"]`

Comment: I am still looking into this, yes. I would like to iterate over each of the answers to the question. I will try what you suggested and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `Questions` is a list. Like the error says, the index must be an integer.

The first question is going to be `data["Questions"][0]`, the second is `data["Questions"][1]` and so on.

If you want the value of "Q1" for the first question, you need to use `data["Questions"][0]["Q1"]`

Comment: Yep! This worked. I understand now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
import json
with open("questions.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["Questions"][0]["Q1"], data["Questions"][1]["Q1"])
```